# Cannot view total number of flags raised

Tags: support, flag-history

For the past hour or so I have been unable to view my total flags raised (by clicking on the 'helpful flags raised' link on my profile (see attached picture)):

[image]

When clicked it spends a while attempting to load the page but eventually takes me the page saying that 'something bad happened' and to 'give us additional information about this error'.

**Additional Information**:

- Been happening for ~ 1 hour.
- Cleared my cache to no avail
- Using Chrome (Version 49.0.2623.112 m) although issue also happens on Internet Explorer
- Tried logging in and out which made no difference.

It seems to only be happening when attempting to get to this page and the rest of the site is behaving as expected.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this also (latest Firefox if it matters).

Comment: It works for me but it takes 10-20 seconds to load

Comment: I'm with @NathanOliver, works but super slow.

Comment: Oddly enough, the flag count for me _on MSO_ works fine- Only on Main do I have an issue. (Mine is slow, but ultimately loads the "Oops" page.) Same version Chrome as the OP.

Comment: Due to this post the [Bosun](https://bosun.org/) graph for timed-out queries per minute is probably off the scale...

Comment: Works fine for me on all sites.

Comment: Whatever was broken/tired is now working again!